# Range Error: invalid status code: 0

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

i am new in nodejs, i have used visual studio 2015 web express for learn about node js development. 
Every thing works fine & run simple app.get method smoothly and now i want to retrieve some list from nodejs, but it not works.

I have read an article and try to implement. [Check here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/nodejs/1032/nodejs-apps-in-visual-studio-mean-stack)

I have following code:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var port = process.env.port || 1337;

var app = express();
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 
extended: true
}));


app.get('/api/list', function (request, response) {
response.status(200).json(
    { "movieId": 1, "name": "The Pacific Rim" },
    { "movieId": 2, "name": "Transformer" });
});

app.listen(port);
```

I am getting following error in browser when I visit "http://localhost:1337/api/list"

```
RangeError: Invalid status code: 0
at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:192:11)
at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:157:8)
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (_http_outgoing.js:574:10)
at ServerResponse.send (c:\users\XYZ12\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NodeMovieList\NodeMovieList\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:211:10)
at ServerResponse.json (c:\users\XYZ12\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NodeMovieList\NodeMovieList\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:256:15)
at ServerResponse.send (c:\users\XYZ12\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NodeMovieList\NodeMovieList\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
at c:\users\XYZ12\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NodeMovieList\NodeMovieList\server.js:22:14
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\users\XYZ12\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NodeMovieList\NodeMovieList\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (c:\users\XYZ12\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NodeMovieList\NodeMovieList\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (c:\users\XYZ12\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\NodeMovieList\NodeMovieList\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually sending an array to the response, you are passing a second argument which is the status code argument.

Here is your code

```
json(
    { "movieId": 1, "name": "The Pacific Rim" },
    { "movieId": 2, "name": "Transformer" }
);
```

Here is what you should do :

```
json([
        { "movieId": 1, "name": "The Pacific Rim" },
        { "movieId": 2, "name": "Transformer" }
]);
```

You were missing the square brackets for defining an array.

Here is a correct version of your code :

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var port = 1337;

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));


app.get('/api/list', function (request, response) {
    response.status(200).json([
        { "movieId": 1, "name": "The Pacific Rim" },
        { "movieId": 2, "name": "Transformer" }
    ]);
});

app.listen(port);
```